# Changing properties in tab bar More page

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a tab based app that has 6 view controllers. The SDK puts the last two controllers on a More page. I would like to access the More page so I can change the color properties. It uses a default blue navbar, but my app uses black bars throughout and I'd like to control some properties on the More page.

But since this page is set up by the SDK, I'm not sure how to access it.  How can I access the More page and control its properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can access it through its tab bar item's related view controller, and then change the navigation bar color from there. I'd provide an example, but I'm not sure of the exact names of everything, its in the documentation though.